# What is the difference between Unicast RPF and Reverse Path Forwarding?

Tags: routing, ipv4, multicast

What is the difference between Unicast RPF and Reverse Path Forwarding? They both verify the source address of each packet before forwarding it to the destination.

Is Reverse Path Forwarding used only when the network wants to build a shared tree of multicast communication and then we need to use Unicast RPF after the shared tree is created?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Both Reverse Path Forwarding and Unicast Reverse path Forwarding do basically the same thing: Verify that the data is coming from the same direction you would expect it to come from. Their function is slightly different though:

- 'Normal' RPF will check the source of **multicast** traffic, to avoid network loops.
- uRPF will check the source of **unicast** traffic, to mitigate IP spoofing.